# COUNTIFS formula to count unique records where range contains dates within specified year criteria

Tags: excel, date

I've been Googling for hours trying to create a COUNTIFS formula that will:

1. count the unique records in a table range
2. that have dates that fall within 4 years after
3. a year in a referenced cell

This is what I have so far:  `=COUNTIFS(dte_degr_conferred2,"<="&YEAR('Student Success and Progress'!$G$1)+4)` but it is not correct and I've tried several variations

Please note:  `dte_degr_conferred2` column contains dates,  `'Student Success and Progress'!$G$1` contains a 4-digit year

Many Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a COUNTIFS or are you exploring different alternatives e.g. VBA?

Comment: I have worked with vba and would love to have any insight, but just a heads-up that the resulting count of this calculation will be used with other formula calculated values that generate chart data...in case this is a deterrent to your proposed solution.

Comment: If you have two dates being 1-Jan-2000 and G1 of that other sheet contains some date in 2002, you want to get a count of 2 (2 same dates) based on just these dates?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this **array formula****:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(dte_degr_conferred2<>"",IF(YEAR(dte_degr_conferred2)='Student Success and Progress'!G1,dte_degr_conferred2)),dte_degr_conferred2),1))
```

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Answer (score 0):

Trying to work out exactly what you need (you might be overcomplicating). Here is an example of using the `COUNTIFS` formula to compare dates. This formula was entered into cell **E6** with the setup as below:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,"<="&E3+4,$B$2:$B$6,">="&E3)
```

[image]

Comment: This works if OP adds a Year column for dte_degr_conferred2. To meet the "within 4 years" criteria, you may need to change "<=" to "<".

Comment: The data in column B would be dates instead of years.

Answer (score 0):

I have an even more simplistic interpretation:

```
=COUNTIF(dte_degr_conferred2,">="&DATE('Student Success and Progress'!$G$1+4,1,1))
```

Comment: That counts dates that are later than 4 years, but I think OP wants a sum of dates that are *within* 4 years.

Comment: True, it would help to see actual data.

Comment: need a count of all UNIQUE records with a date (in mm/dd/yyyy format) within 4 years of the year referenced in 'Student Success and Progress'!$G$1.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to work with now, but it is returning too many records.  I suspect it is not giving me only a count of records unique to the id_num2 range.

Comment: =SUM(COUNTIFS(dte_degr_conferred2,"<="&'Student Success and Progress'!$C$1+1460,cohort_cde2,RIGHT('Student Success and Progress'!$G$1,2)&"FBF"),(1/COUNTIF(id_num2,"<>"&"")),0)

Comment: I am trying to now approach this from referencing a cell with a date that is calculated using G1 since I can't seem to filter dates using just a year.  I've also added another criteria to the mix for the cohort_cde2 named range.

Comment: anyway, none of this seems to be working so far.  I believe the complication is combining multiple criteria with unique records.  I've seen some simple examples, but I can't seem to translate it into the complexity of the solution that I need.

Comment: Here is one of the places where I found reference to what I am looking for:  http://www.get-digital-help.com/2013/10/05/count-unique-distinct-values-with-a-condition/#count

Comment: It's the same thing that I need (unique records with additional criteria) except my additional criteria is much more complex.  Version is Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The "count unique" requirement makes this an interesting question.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
=SUM(
  IF(
   FREQUENCY(
    IF((YEAR(ddc)>=ssp!$G$1) + (YEAR(ddc)<ssp!$G$1+4) = 2, ddc, ""),
    IF((YEAR(ddc)>=ssp!$G$1) + (YEAR(ddc)<ssp!$G$1+4) = 2, ddc, "")
   )>0,
   1
  )
 )
```

... where `ddc` is `dte_degr_conferred2` and `ssp` is `'Student Success and Progress'`.  *(When posting to SO, it's helpful to reduce a question to its essentials, because that makes it easier to respond to, as well as making it more universally useful.)*

Enter as an array formula:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Example**

[image]

In this example, there are three distinct dates that match the criteria:  05/12/2014, 09/12/2014, and 05/26/2012.

**How it works:**

When creating array formulas, it can be useful to work out the calculations separately before joining them in an array.  I've done so here:

[image]

Column C is `=(YEAR(A1)>=$B$1) + (YEAR(A1)<$B$1+4)` (copied down).  In Excel, TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0, so you can add boolean values together.  If `A1` is between `B1` and `B1+4`, both operands are TRUE, and TRUE + TRUE = 2.

Column D is `=IF(C1=2,A1,"")` (copied down).  This grabs the data that matches the criteria.  (I formatted as numbers to highlight the fact that Excel stores dates as numbers.)

Column E is `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(D1:D10,D1:D10)>0,1))`.  For an explanation of this method, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

My solution at top combines all this into a single array formula.